# how to remove the extra spaces in UILabel in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a string coming from web service like below
//coming string is like below format. As user commented unusually.For eg User pressed New lines three times,entered text and again pressed new line and posted the comment as below

Super

How to remove the new lines, spaces other stuff other than text in UILabel.I tried with below code but it is not trimmed..

```
NSString* result = [mystring stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
     custom.mylabel.text=result;

//also tried with below code

custom.mylabel.text=[mystring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];

custom.mylabel.text=[mystring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@""];
```

Please suggest any ideas how to fix it..

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 2):

```
text = [text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]
```

Comment: Thanks..But I have posted the same code in my question that I tried this..But not working as expected..

Answer (score 1):

NSString *trimmed = [textStr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
    NSString * val = @"(555) 555-555 Off\nice \n";
    NSString * strippedNumber = [val stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[^a-z^A-Z]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [val length])];
    NSLog(@"%@", strippedNumber);
```

`O/P:`-Office